# Call to a member function get on a non-object

Tags: php

I have this class:

```
class Search
{
    protected static $Basics;

    public function __construct() {
        self::$Basics = new Basics();
    }

    public static function getT() {
        return self::$Basics->get('keywords/t');
    }

    public static function isAvailable($keyword) {
        return self::$Basics->get('keywords/available', ['keyword' => $keyword])['available'];
    }
}
```

The class `Basics` is really simple class:

```
class Basics
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        //some code..
    }
    public function get($keyword, $param = null)
    {
        return ['available' => true];
    }
}
```

Call to `getT` function:

```
use App\Libraries\Search;
class GV
{
    public function test() {
        echo Search::getT() ? 'ok' : 'bad';
    }
}
```

But, when i run the function `getT` in class `Search`, it return this error: `Call to a member function get() on a non-object`

What can i do?

Comment: As your `get()` method has 2 mandatory arguments, calling it with only 1 (`return self::$Basics->get('keywords/t');`) will fail

Comment: @MarkBaker I edited my question

Comment: Otherwise, there are no problems with the code as written

Comment: @MarkBaker it return this error: `Call to a member function get() on a non-object`, Maybe because i using Laravel framework? It is connected?

Comment: can you show us the part of the code where you call getT() ?

Comment: `__construct` method is never run because you're calling the methods in __static__ context

Comment: Impossible to tell; it ran without error [when I tested it a few minutes ago](https://3v4l.org/oJe6E)

Comment: There's an error there when you call `Search::getT();` statically, but not if you properly instantiate it via `new Search`, @MarkBaker. I'm assuming that's what he's doing as, like you mentioned, the code posted itself produces no errors at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the method inside `Search` statically (`Search::getT();`) which will never fire the `__construct()` method.

`__construct()` gets fired upon instantiating the class (`$search = new Search;`), not upon calling static methods (`Class::method();`).

Simply instantiate your search object: `$search = new Search;`

Like so:

```
use App\Libraries\Search;
class GV
{
    public function test() {
        $search = new Search;
        echo $search::getT() ? 'ok' : 'bad';
    }
}
```